# How to record video from images without leak memory in Swift?

Tags: ios

I have a task in my project about camera security. The system is old tech, so live video of camera by receiving images from server and show on UIImageView continuously. Now, I want to record video and save to gallery of device.

When user tap the record button, I will append images received from server into array images. After that I will export video from array images when user stop record.

Everything work well with short recording time. However, if user record video with long time, number of images append into array will be a lot and the app will be leak out memory and crash.

I tried using Mi Home (The app Camera Security of Xaomi) and it handle so good record video. How can I resolve this case?

Thanks and Cheers!